# Flexbox grow or shrink makes the div shift slightly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, flexbox

I am using flexbox to design this navigation bar
[image]

Eveything is working fine except for two problems:

- The second div grows and shrinks as required but when the content gets too large the second div shifts to the left slightly.
- I can't understand how to place a 4th div just below div 2(which should also grow and shrink like div 2) while maintaining all four in the same line as this is my first time with flexbox implementation. Ex:
  [image]
  The 4th div should be in the position of black mark and both the text and black mark should be vertically centered.

```css
html,
body {
  background-image: url("../images/theme1.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}

.conversationHeader {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border: none;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.headerOnScroll {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.horizontalLayout {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0 9px!important;
  height: 68px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.conversationBackButton {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px!important;
  margin-right: 16px;
  color: #1D333E!important;
  display: inline-flex;
}

.conversationDetails {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-family: robotoregular, 'sans-serif'!important;
  font-size: 18px!important;
  color: #546770;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}

.avatar {
  min-width: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
}

.composeMessageContainer {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top conversationHeader headerOnScroll">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header horizontalLayout">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-center conversationBackButton">
        <span class="ionicons ion-android-arrow-back"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="conversationDetails">John Doe</div>
      <img class="img-circle img-responsive avatar" src="images/dp.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid navbar-fixed-bottom composeMessageContainer">
  Text
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see point #1. What shifts left? I filled up the second div with text and nothing changed. https://jsfiddle.net/r2df3jmj/

Comment: For point #2, you can repeat the same layout from the top row. Except, on the second row, add `visibility: hidden` to the first and third divs.

Comment: Otherwise, consider a CSS Grid layout solution.

Comment: if you fill realy loooooooooooooong text, then it happens.

Comment: See the demo I posted. I did post long text. Nothing changed.

Comment: @Michael_B strange! Here the same code produces a little shift to the right when long texts are filled. But when I do according to LGSon, it fixes the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add `flex-shrink: 0` to the `.conversationBackButton` and `.avatar` it should work fine, as it will prevent them to shrink

```
.conversationBackButton {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px!important;
  margin-right: 16px;
  color: #1D333E!important;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;             /* added  */
}

.avatar {
  min-width: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  flex-shrink: 0;             /* added  */
}
```

---

<strike>To make the 4th `div` line up with the 2nd, move its markup the `navbar-header horizontalLayout`, remove `navbar-fixed-bottom` and change its CSS rule to this</strike>

```
.composeMessageContainer {
  flex-basis: calc(100% - 56px - 40px);
  margin-left: 56px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Update after a question edit

To make the 4th `div` line up with the 2nd, move its markup the `conversationDetails`, put the existing text in `conversationDetails` in its own `div` and remove `navbar-fixed-bottom`

```
.composeMessageContainer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Stack snipper

```css
html,
body {
  background-image: url("../images/theme1.png");
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
body {
  padding-top: 80px;
}

.conversationHeader {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border: none;
  min-height: 60px;
  display: block;
}

.headerOnScroll {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 6px -3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.horizontalLayout {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0!important;
  padding: 0 9px!important;
  height: 68px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
}

.conversationBackButton {
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 8px!important;
  margin-right: 16px;
  color: #1D333E!important;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-shrink: 0;             /* added  */
}

.conversationDetails {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  font-family: robotoregular, 'sans-serif'!important;
  font-size: 18px!important;
  color: #546770;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: block;
}

.avatar {
  min-width: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  flex-shrink: 0;             /* added  */
}

.composeMessageContainer {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top conversationHeader headerOnScroll">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header horizontalLayout">
      <a class="navbar-brand text-center conversationBackButton">
        <span class="ionicons ion-android-arrow-back"></span>
      </a>
      <div class="conversationDetails">
        <div>John Doe</div>
        <div class="composeMessageContainer">
          Text
        </div>
      </div>
      <img class="img-circle img-responsive avatar" src="images/dp.png">
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: nopes you didn't get me. I meant the fourth div to be just below the second div and in between div 1 and div 3

Comment: @Ayan Updated my answer

Comment: You got me correct, see my updated question how I want it. Your fiddle has some space between the two vertical divs

Comment: @Ayan Updated again

Comment: Damn it was so easy!? :O Then I can add overflow properties to this div too right?

Comment: @Ayan You should be able to do that, yes. If you ran into issues, drop me a line here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153584/discussion-between-ayan-and-lgson).